# When does the Frobenius Norm equal normalized inner product?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products

Assume you need to design an image retrieval system where you want
to find similar images to a query image $X \in \Bbb{R}^{N \times M}$ among the database
images $Y_{k} \in \Bbb{R}^{N \times M}$

You have two options, using the Frobenius norm: $\operatorname{dis}(X,Y_{k}) = \left \| X-Y_{k} \right \|_{F}$
or the normalized inner product:
$$\operatorname{sim}(X,Y_{k}) = \frac{\operatorname{tr}(X^{T}Y_{k})}{\left \|X  \right \|_{F}\left \|Y_{k}  \right \|_{F}}$$

My Question is:

> Under which condition will a system using the Frobenius norm
> yield the same result than a system that uses the normalized inner
> product?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't follow your question here. What do you mean by a "system" here? And what "result" are you talking about? The normalised inner product and the Frobenius norm measure quite different things, specifically (and respectively) the angle between two vectors (ignoring their length) and the distance between two points. Is there a particular reason why you are comparing their values?

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry about that. System 1 would be comparing images with the Frobenius Norm. System 2 would use the normalized inner product to compare images. Basically I am looking for how system 1 relates to system 2 and under which condition I can make them equal. See my edit also.

Comment: What are the norms in the denominator of $\operatorname{sim}(\cdot,\cdot)$? Are they Frobenius norms as well?

Comment: @user1551 yes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both systems will return the same results if the “image matrices” would already be normalized to unit norm. In this case, one can easily show that the $|| X – Y_k||_F^2 = 2 – 2*tr({X^T * Y_k})$, i.e., they will result in the same ranking.